# How can i iterate through scene children in three js

Tags: javascript, function, three.js

Using three js:

I have a function `removeBysid(id)`

What i want to do is go into all of the children in my scene and check the `treeNode` of the third child and get its unique `sid` (a variable I created).

In the console when I do :

> `scene.children[4].children[0].children[0].treeNode`

I get what I want to achieve with the function.

Now I want a function to iterate all of the children without hardcoding the index like I did in the console.

```
function removeBysid(id) {
 scene.traverse(function(element) {
    //element returns Scene {uuid: "AC30E121-517A-40F9-8F86-F3626003A3C7", name: "", type: "Scene", parent: null, //children: Array(6)…} now i want to check scene.children[4].children[0].children[0].treeNode.sid = sid
 })
}
```

Comment: [`traverse`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D.traverse) is a [recursive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/recursion-javascript) method, so it will automatically iterate your entire scene. Place a breakpoint, console log, or alert inside the given function, and you can see it being called for every object. Give checking for your `sid` a try, and update your post if you encounter any problems or errors.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look somewhat like this:

```
function removeBysid(id) {
    scene.traverse(function(element) {
        if (element.children[0].children[0].treeNode.sid == id) {
            scene.remove(scene.getObjectById(element.id);
            // And since you know it's unique...
            return;
        }
    })
}
```